# Going on a 2 month exchange program and I don't know what will happen to my muscle gains

Tags: bodybuilding, gym, muscle-loss

This December I'm leaving for an exchange program in the United States in which I will be spending 1 month in a family home in California, and the rest of the time touring around the country.

The thing is that it's likely that I wont be able to hit the gym for these 2 months. How bad will this affect my body, and how can I try to make this muscle loss not that drastic?

Comment: Fitness is very much an "easy come, easy go" thing. If you went on one of those "get fit in 12 weeks" programs, you will only have made superficial gains, which will fade quickly if not maintained. But if you've been working out for years, your gains are deep-rooted, and won't disappear in a month unless you REALLY let yourself go on the all-American fast foods. In order to accomodate a proper answer, please elaborate more on what kind of fitness level you're at, how long you've been working out etc.

Comment: I´ve been working out since February, i´m not that experienced but i'm not a 12 week fit person